# variables undeclared when wrapped with CSV serialization

Tags: xml, xquery, basex

I have a query that runs over ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov//biosample/biosample_set.xml.gz in Basex 9.5.1

```
for $bsattrib in doc(
  'biosample_set'
)/BioSampleSet/BioSample/Attributes/Attribute

let $attribdata := data(
  $bsattrib
)
let $attrib_name := data(
  $bsattrib/@attribute_name
)
let $attrib_hn := data(
  $bsattrib/@harmonized_name
)
let $bs := $bsattrib/../..
let $bsaccession := data(
  $bs/@accession
)

group by $attrib_hn

order by  count(
  $bs
) descending

return <record>
<hname>{$attrib_hn}</hname>
<bs_count>{count($bs)}</bs_count>
</record>
```

giving

```xml
<record>
  <hname/>
  <bs_count>59840</bs_count>
</record>
<record>
  <hname>gap_accession</hname>
  <bs_count>39179</bs_count>
</record>
<record>
  <hname>submitter_handle</hname>
  <bs_count>39179</bs_count>
</record>
```

etc.

When I wrap that with

```
declare option output:method "csv";
declare option output:csv "header=yes, separator=semicolon";

<csv>
```

at the top and

```
</csv>
```

at the bottom, I get

> Undeclared variable: $attrib

Answer (score 0):

Duh, I had the `<csv>` tags in the wrong place

```
return <csv><record>
<hname>{$attrib_hn}</hname>
<bs_count>{count($bs)}</bs_count>
</record></csv>
```